# C program to find the number of elements in an array after inserting and without counting while inserting

Tags: c, arrays, count, integer, strlen

Looking for a C program to count the number of elements in an integer array after inserting and without counting while inserting.Alternatively, what is the integer array substitution for strlen() ?
In this program I need to determine the value of c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[300],mx=0,c=0,i=0,j;
 for(i=0;i<=300;i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    if(a[i]=='q') break;
 }
 c=??;
 for(j=0;j<=c;j++)
 {
     printf("%d\n",a[j]);
     if(a[j]>mx) mx=a[j];
 }
 printf("Max=%d\n",mx);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have one too many ++i's in your input loop.  Also, after the input loop i is exactly the number for which you are looking -- although that seems to violate your condition of "don't count while inserting".

Answer (score 0):

From Your input seems that once you get `q`(113D) input you stop accepting any more input from user.

So need to iterate through array until you found `q` to get array length.

```
for(c=0;a[c] != 113;c++)
{
      //do nothing
} 

//Now you can use c as array length
```

I guess there is no alternative way like `strlen()` for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i = 0; i < 300; ++i)
 {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);  /* TODO: check if return value != 1 -> input error */
    if (a[i] == 'q') 
      break;
 }

 for(j = 0; j < 300 && a[j] != 'q'; ++j)
 {
     printf("%d\n", a[j]);
     if (a[j] > mx) 
       mx = a[j];
 }
```

As vagish noted, having the input be terminated by 'q' in the way you attempt is pretty strange.  The input "113" will map to the ASCII value of 'q', so that input value can't be processed by your program.  Furthermore, if somebody actually tried to enter "q" to end the input, I believe the scanf would fail, return 0 and leave a[i] uninitialized, which is definitely not what you want.

You probably want your input to be terminated by EOF instead (ctrl-D if you are typing it into a terminal on most platforms) and you want to check the return code of your call to scanf for input errors and EOF.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. But how to count inputs when  EOF is used @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4564515/jschultz410

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my question. Smart vertion of the above program:

## include

int main()

{

```
double a[100000],mx=0;

int i,j,c=0;

printf("Enter as many numbers as you wish . Press Ctrl+D or any character to stop inputting :\n");


for(i=0;i<100000;i++)

{
    if((scanf("%lf",&a[i]))==1)

        c++;

    //else break;
}

for(j=0;j<c;j++)

{
    if(a[j]>mx) mx=a[j];
}

printf("You have inserted %d values and the maximum is:%g",c,mx);

return 0;
```

}